# "The very minute after"

Tags: phrases

In which cases is *very* used with the same meaning it has in a phrase like "the very minute after"?
Is it a set phrase, or are there other similar phrases?

> The very minute after I leave, they start taking my books from the shelf, reading them, and leaving them in the kitchen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Very* is acting here in a sense closer to its old meaning of *truly*, *precisely*, *literally*:

> You’re the very man they’re looking for!

> The very fact that we’re alive is a miracle.

The given sentence is very similar to:

> Literally the minute after I leave, they start taking my books from the shelf…

The evolution that *very* underwent, from this older sense to its more common modern usage as an intensifier, is the very same shift in meaning that *literally* is now undergoing, to the chagrin of many pedants.

Comment: In that sense I would say the closest substitute word would be *actual*.

Comment: "exact" or "self-same" would also be usable in this context.

Answer (score 2):

When *[very](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/very#Adjective)* is used in that context, it takes the place of *[mere](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mere#Etymology_3)*, the form originally derived from the Latin *merus* (meaning pure or undiluted), a comparitive meaning "nothing less than" or "downright", or indeed "just", "only", "no more than".

In that context it particularly means *immediately* or *"as soon as"*.  It is pretty much always prefixed with "the".

> The *very* idea of it.
>
> The *very* best of luck.
>
> That is the *very* worst thing that could have happened.

Answer (score 1):

From [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com):

> "very: precise; particular: That is
>   the very item we want."

It can be used with a variety of nouns. From http://pinedalepumpkinpatch.blogspot.com/2009/08/giant-pumpkin-in-making.html

> "You may see the very pumpkin that you
>   wish to purchase."

From http://fuckyeahtvpicspam.tumblr.com/post/379433655/daisy-what-do-you-say-the-very-second-were-done:

> "DAISY: What do you say the very
>   second we're done here, we go back to
>   my place for a drink?"

Answer (score 1):

*Very* is just a means to give emphasis to something. In your example, "The *very* minute after I leave..." gives emphasis to people taking the person's books the moment he/she leaves and so on (though I think *the very minute I leave...* is better usage).
Another example of *very* used for emphasis is:

> You're the very person I need to talk
>   to...

Or

> This is the very book I was looking for